# Can white Gaussian noise improve signal level in non-linear device?

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, non-linear

In the system shown below, can white Gaussian noise amplify or attenuate the input signal?
[image]

Most of the time we check signal level proportional to noise level (such as noise figure) not singly.

I have obtained PSD of my desire system's output and it is a combination of

- a) Dc term
- b) reaction of input noise to itself
- c) reaction of input signal to itself
- d) reaction of input signal and input noise.

At system's output at frequency $\omega$ should I assume terms (c) and (d) as the signal level? Or c is enough?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like you're asking if there are situations where you might add noise to a signal before it is input to a nonlinear device. The answer is yes; this technique is called [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither), and can be used to turn what would be deterministic quantization errors in an ADC (resulting in discrete spectral artifacts) into random errors, flattening the quantization noise spectrum.

Comment: Dithering is a specific example of a more general idea - see stochastic resonance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the noise process has correlation with the input signal, then it is theoretically possible, no matter what kind of device you use.

Answer (score 1):

As Jason R. says in the comment, dither will do this.  Another phrase to look for is [**noise shaping**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_shaping) where the noise spectrum can be reshaped to not interfere with the signal of interest.